# Removing newlines between tags in html in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, removing-whitespace

I want trim down all the white spaces and new line and turn the result from

```
<title>

     Asian Case Research Journal (World Scientific)

</title>
```

to this

```
<title>Asian Case Research Journal (World Scientific)</title>
```

My code:

```
for link in url_list:
    try:
    r = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")
    print(soup.title)
except:
    print("No Title Found ")
    continue
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import bs4

html = '''<title>

     Asian Case Research Journal (World Scientific)

</title>'''
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
title = soup.title
title.string = title.get_text(strip=True)
print(str(title))
```

out:

```
<title>Asian Case Research Journal (World Scientific)</title>
```

In bs4, tag is an Object which has string attribute, you can access or modify it with `.` notation, and convert the tag object to python str object by using `str(tag)`

Document: [modifying-string](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#modifying-string)

Answer (score 1):

Try this and modify it for your use case.

```
desired_string = ''.join([x.strip() for x in str(soup.title).split('\r\n')])
```

Answer (score 0):

`soup.title.text.strip()` should do it